# How can I copy charts from Excel to an existing Word document I already have open?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I spend a lot of my work day manually copying and pasting charts from Excel into Word and I'm trying to make something to automate the process for me.

I have made a workbook that allows me to select an Excel book to get the charts from and a Word document to paste to from a pair of dropdown lists that automatically populate with all the Excel/Word documents I have open at any given time. This bit seems to work fine.

The macro I've written is meant to take the names of these files and save them as strings, then use GetObject to select the Word document I want to copy to. The idea is to then use a Do-Loop and an If-Else statement to run down through a list of test references I paste into the sheet and copy-paste each chart over from Excel to Word in order.

When I run it though, I get the following error:

"Run-time error '4160': Application-defined or object-defined error"

**I've tried looking on other forums, and all the advice I can find talks about creating new Word documents to paste to, rather than pasting to an existing document I already have open.**

Macro code below. N.B The Do Loop/If Statement section isn't finished yet, but I don't think this is where the problem lies.

Any help greatly appreciated!

```
Sub ExportCharts()

'Define Excel Variables
Dim TestRef As String
Dim TestType As String
Dim Book1 As Excel.Workbook
Dim Book2 As Excel.Workbook
Dim DisplaySheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ChartSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ChartRng As Range
Dim BookName As String
Dim DocName As String
    
'Define Word Variables
Dim WordApp As Object
Dim WordDoc As Object

Set Book1 = Excel.Workbooks("Chart Export.xlsm")

Book1.Activate
Book1.Worksheets("Input").Activate

'Set Book and Doc names
BookName = Book1.Worksheets("Input").Range("E2").Value
DocName = Book1.Worksheets("Input").Range("E5").Value

Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
With WordApp
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
End With

'Set destination document
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents("DocName")

'MACRO SEEMS TO BREAK HERE

'Set source workbook
Set Book2 = Excel.Workbooks("BookName")

'Select first test ref
Range("C2").Select

    'Run down list of test refs in order
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        
        Book1.Activate
        Book1.Worksheets("Input").Activate
    
        'Set test reference and type
        TestRef = ActiveCell.Value
        TestType = Left(TestRef, 1)
    
            'If test type = airborne
            If TestType = "A" Then
            
                Book2.Activate
                
                'Set display and chart worksheets to airborne
                Set DisplaySheet = Book.Worksheets("5 Airborne Display")
                Set ChartSheet = Book.Worksheets("6 Airborne Chart")
                
                DisplaySheet.Activate
            
                'Set test reference in display worksheet
                DisplaySheet.Range("D5") = TestRef
            
                'Activate chart worksheet
                ChartSheet.Activate
                
                'Select chart range in chart worksheet
                Set ChartRng = ChartSheet.Range("A3:AG61")
            
                'Copy chart as picture
                ChartRng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
            
                'Pause Application (helps with stability)
                Application.Wait Now() + #12:00:02 AM#
            
                'Activate destination document
                WordDoc.Activate
                
                'Paste Chart
                WordDoc.Selection.Paste
                
            End If
        
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

I've tried looking on other forums and YouTube videos, but all the advice I can find seems to relate to creating new Word docs rather than pasting to one I already have open.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an object variable to either Word Document or Excel Worksheet, if the items were previously saved and loaded in the application the reference name has to be the Name.Ext format.

For Word

```
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents("DocName.docm")

Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents("DocName.docx")
```

For Excel

```
Set Book2 = Excel.Workbooks("BookName.xlsm")

Set Book2 = Excel.Workbooks("BookName.xlsx")
```

depends on that with or w/o macro were they saved.

Answer (score 0):

If `Hide extensions for known file types` is enabled, Word/Excel captions exclude extensions. But references in code require the full name with extension.

```
Sub demo()
    Dim doc As Document
    For Each doc In Application.Documents
        Debug.Print doc.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

The code returns the full filename if the document is saved.

[image]